# Crossing bound implies Reidemeister move bound?

Tags: knot-theory

In 1998 Galatolo established an [upper bound on the number of Reidemeister moves needed to convert a diagram $D$ of the unknot into a trivial loop diagram](http://www.bdim.eu/item?fmt=pdf&id=RLIN_1998_9_9_4_299_0). The upper bound is a function of $n$, the number of crossings in $D$.

Galatolo reduced the problem to that of limiting the number of crossings the diagram can have during the conversion process. Specifically, he states these problems:

> **Problem 1.** Find some function $f$ such that converting $D$ into a trivial diagram takes at most $f(n)$ Reidemeister moves.
>
> **Problem 2.** Find some function $F$ such that converting $D$ into a trivial diagram never passes through an intermediate diagram with more than $F(n)$ crossings.

He claims that these problems are trivially equivalent in his footnote labelled $(\,^1)$, part of which says

> If we have $F(n)$ then $f(n) < 2^{2F(n)(\log 2F(n) + 1)}$

I don't understand how a bound $F(n)$ on crossings can lead to a bound on moves, because one could do many Type III Reidemeister moves, none of which affect the number of crossings. One could bound the number of essentially different diagrams resulting from Type III moves, but that would not be as trivial as Galatolo claims. Am I missing something?

And by the way, should the bound actually be $f(n) < 2^{2F(n)(\log_2 F(n) + 1)}$? (log base 2)

*[(This question was originally on math.stackexchange)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770838/crossing-bound-implies-reidemeister-move-bound)*

**My solution** starts with a bound of the number of diagrams with crossing number $k$. Every $k$-crossing diagram consists of $k$ "crossing units" that look like $\times$ except with some overstrand and understrand assignment. The four "legs" of the crossing unit are connected to the other "legs" in some way. The number of ways to partition $4k$ legs into pairs is $\frac{(4k)!}{2^{2k}(2k)!}$ (explained in [an MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35684/combination-of-splitting-elements-into-pairs)), and the overstrand/understrand assignments contribute another factor of $2^k$. Ambient isotopic diagrams obviously correspond to the same "leg pairing". The matching may create more crossings but no matter; we have
$$
\text{No. of diagrams with $k$ crossings} \leq \frac{(4k)!}{2^k(2k)!} \leq 2^{-k}(4k)^{2k} = 2^{2k(\log_2 k + 3)}
$$

So, assuming $D$ can be converted to the trivial diagram without passing through a diagram with more than $F(n)$ crossings, there are at most $F(n)2^{2F(n)(\log_2 F(n) + 3)}$ different intermediate diagrams. Therefore at most $F(n)2^{2F(n)(\log_2 F(n) + 3)}$ Reidemeister moves are necessary for the conversion.

> My bound is significantly larger than Galatolo's. If anyone should provide a simpler way to derive Galatolo's bound, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: My guess is that the intended idea is just the one you say, that the number of essentially different diagrams is small. And yes, I think the log should be base two. But in fact the number of diagrams can be bounded singly-exponentially in F, rather than exponentially in F log F (this part is not so trivial).

Comment: I would like to point out that Lackenby proved in 2013 that the number of Reidemeister moves needed to convert a diagram of the unknot into the trivial diagram is polynomial w.r.t. the number of crossings: http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0180

Comment: @DavidEppstein I have attempted my own bound (see the original question) but it's still $F2^{F \log F}$. How did you bound it exponentially in $F \log F$?

Comment: There are a single-exponential number of 4-regular planar graphs  with $n$ vertices, and a single-exponential number of ways of choosing the above-below relation at each crossing.

Comment: @DavidEppstein do you have a reference for that bound on 4-regular planar graphs? (I hope it's not asymptotic)

Comment: The fact that the number of unlabeled maximal planar graphs with $n$ vertices is single-exponential is from Tutte, "A census of planar triangulations", Canad. J. Math. 1962. A 4-regular planar graph can be encoded as a maximal planar graph on the same vertices together with an annotation of which edges to keep in a 4-regular subgraph. And Tutte gives a very explicit formula (in terms of ratios of factorials, but you can easily convert it to single-exponential form using Stirling's approximation) not just O-notation.

Comment: Assuming Galatolo means $\log_2$, the main difference between your bound and his is the $+3$ vs. $+1$. Is that what you're interested in? Because it seems like by using better upper bounds on the factorial you can save $2 \log_2 e$, which is enough to close the gap and also absorb the multiplicative factor of $F$. This requires $k$ sufficiently large, but one could pretty easily find the explicit $k$.